# Response includes stacktrace even though DebugMode and WriteErrorsToResponse are disabled

Tags: servicestack

I am running a self-hosted API on the latest version of ServiceStack (5.6.0).

I am struggling to deal with exceptions early on in the request processing pipeline. More specifically when requests contains `|` characters. The API will always return a full error response with the stackTrace. Even in a release build with `DebugMode` and `WriteErrorsToResponse` disabled.

Normally I don't have problem since most issues are handled in a custom ServiceRunner with a custom error response DTO. But this error happens before the ServiceRunner is called.

How do I go about disabling the stackTrace? And would it be possible to replace the error response with a custom response?

This is the response object I'll receive when hitting e.g. `http://localhost:80/*|?`

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "errorCode": "ArgumentException",
        "message": "Illegal characters in path.",
        "stackTrace": "   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n   at System.IO.Path.InternalCombine(String path1, String path2)\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.GetFullSearchString(String fullPath, String searchPattern)\r\n   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory.GetFileFromBackingDirectoryOrDefault(String fName)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualPathProviderBase.GetFile(String virtualPath)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.HttpListener.ListenerRequest.GetFile()\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.HttpListener.ListenerRequest.get_IsFile()\r\n   at ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory.GetHandlerForPathInfo(IHttpRequest httpReq, String filePath)\r\n   at ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler(IHttpRequest httpReq)\r\n   at ServiceStack.AppHostHttpListenerBase.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__8.MoveNext()",
        "errors": null,
        "meta": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f60ae368471d1e142d4493c597bbd409bf13b20b) where it will no longer show StackTraces of HTTP Listener Exceptions when `Config.DebugMode = false`.

This change is available from v5.6.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).